# Async / await issue, getting "A task was canceled."

Tags: c#, task, async-await

I have following line of code in my SDK.

```
public async Task<Object> DoSomething(String v1, string v2)
{
   ......
   var response = await _restClient.DeleteAsync<Object, ISomeAPIError>(endpoint)
   ......
}
```

This code works fine when my test code is using async and await pattern

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test_DomeSomething()
{
   ......
   await x.DoSomething("x", "y");
   ......
}
```

But when I write same test in non-aync way, I get "A task was canceled."

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_DomeSomething_Non_Async()
{
   ......
   x.DoSomething("x", "y");
   ......
}
```

So, one passes and other fails. I do not want my client code to force non-async and I do not want to change my SDK to use .Result and make it non-async.

Searching on the internet talks about setting the timeout property, but it does not makes sense because it is already set for over a min, and one of the test is working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe that's because you really want `DoSomething` to return `void`.

Comment: I want to get some values back. Just to follow your suggestion, even when I changed my method signature to return void it failed with same error. public async Task DoSomething(String v1, string v2)

Comment: If your code is asynchronous, then its callers should be asynchronous. There's no need to try to force a "synchronous" call.

Comment: can't you do `x.DoSomething().Wait()` to wait for the task?

Answer (score 0):

`await` does not make your code asynchronous. Using an asynchronous function makes it async. `await` just pauses the containing method until the awaited task is done.

Therefore, I can tell that you do not know the basics of `await`. Using a technology without understanding it is dangerous.

You cannot make any call synchronous just by omitting `await`. Without `await` the async call will just run "in the background" and operate concurrently with the rest of the code. Who knows what will happen. Concurrency is dangerous.

I do not know what to recommend to you. Probably you should just use `await`. Any reason you can't?

Comment: I am using await and it works fine when my test Method Test_DomeSomething, also uses async\await pattern. But it fails when my test Method does not use async\await Test_DomeSomething_Non_Async. I want to see if there is anything I can do in SDK to make it work both sync and async.

Comment: Of course it fails. Make sure you understand *why*. I don't know what to tell you if you don't even know the basics. Why does it have to work synchronous as well?

Comment: I agree with you. my lead dev wanted it that way. But now he is fine :)